# How to make inputText type-ahead values clickable as like a button in jsf/bootsfaces?

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I have an `inputText` with type-ahead where user can type a job class and a drop-down shows, and then they click on select - it populates the data. But, what I want to do is instead of the "Select" button I want to put a `onclick` or something on my inputText that when the dropdown shows and the user clicks on the drop down value it can populate data that it was doing with my button. Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
           <h:form>

              <b:inputText id = "inputName"  value = "#{myBean.currentJobSelected}" typeahead="true" typeahead-values="#{myBean.cPaySearchList}"
                           placeholder="e.g. Apple" required="true" ajax="true" >


             <f:ajax render=":dTable" />


                </b:inputText>

          <b:commandButton action="#{myBean.getAllMethods}" update=":dTable"  value= " Select" >

              <f:ajax execute="inputName" render=":dTable" />

          </b:commandButton>




            </h:form>
```

Comment: you could try `<b:inputText onclick="ajax:myBean.getAllMethods()" .../>`

Comment: what if - if I have another action that need to happen when they click on the drop-down values?

Comment: You could create a remote command and call it from JavaScript if you are triggering an event through there

Comment: can you please show me some way ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you're looking for something like this:

```
<b:remoteCommand name="onValueSelected" actionListener="#{myBean.myMethod}" update=":dtable" />
<script> 
$('#inputName').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
  onValueSelected();
});
</script>
```

However, I recommend using a CSS class instead of the ID. JSF modifies the IDs, so it's simpler to use a CSS class in the jQuery expression (i.e. `$('.job-selected')` instead of `$('#inputName')` - plus you need to add `class="job-selected"` to the `<b:inputText />`).

Comment: Don't nest the `remoteCommand` into the `inputText`. Apart from that, you're free to move it where it suits you best. Semantically, it belongs to the `inputText`, so I'd put it in the line before or after the `inputText`.